# Windows Credential provider - password expired while desktop locked

Tags: c, winapi, credential-providers

im working on a credential provider and got stuck with the following issue:

When the desktop is locked on a terminal server and the password expires, the CP cant seem to change the password.

I can dectect that the password must be changed in `ReportResult()`, then open a dialog asking for the new password and packing a `KERB_CHANGEPASSWORD_REQUEST` to hand over in `GetSerialization()`. This works when the user logs on initially (CPUS_LOGON).

But in `CPUS_UNLOCK_WORKSTATION` (when the user is already logged in) I get the same `ntsStatus (which is 0xC0000224)` again in `ReportResult()` after handing over the `KERB_CHANGEPASSWORD_REQUEST`

**So i wonder if anybody knows what the difference is between those two scenarios - is logonUI expecting a package other than KERB_CHANGEPASSWORD_REQUEST ?**

I also tried setting the `GetSerializationResponse "status"` from `CPGSR_RETURN_CREDENTIAL_FINISHED` to `CPGSR_NO_CREDENTIAL_FINISHED` (in the technical reference its said to be the indicator that a password change completed, but thats probably for `CPUS_CHANGE_PASSWORD`).

The setup im testing this is on is a Win2012 R2 terminal server with a Win2016 DC.

I'd be grateful for any help, thanks!

Comment: Do your provider receive CPUS_CHANGE_PASSWORD usage scenario after successfully processed CPUS_LOGON or CPUS_UNLOCK_WORKSTATION?

Comment: There is no CPUS_CHANGE_PASSWORD here. The password change happens within CPUS_LOGON or CPUS_UNLOCK_WORKSTATION, eventhough GetSerialization expects a KERB_CHANGEPASSWORD_REQUEST

Comment: Do your provider receive something is `SetSerialisation` method?

Comment: I dont really know where youre going with that question? But i figured Windows itself cant do this either and wants you to sign out and in again to change the expired password. I will guide users to do the same with my cp