# Change password Custom Credential Provider

Tags: windows, credential-providers

I have implemented the Custom Credential Provider. in that, when the user enables the "User must change password at next logon" option. How do i display the change password screen of Windows in my Custom CP or else what i am supposed to do to change the password.

Comment: IMHO your provider will be called twice - first time for logon `CPUS_LOGON`/`CPUS_UNLOCK_WORKSTATION` and the second time for change password `CPUS_CHANGE_PASSWORD`

Comment: Also you could check this [article](https://stackoverflow.com/q/51947828/3868464)